# Ecto - updating nested embed

Tags: elixir, ecto

I can't update nested settings with ecto, I either get "no changes" changeset or errors. Migration:

```
def change do
  create table(:trees) do
  ...
  add :settings, :map
```

Settings looks like:

```
defmodule Final.TreeSettings do
  use Ecto.Schema

  embedded_schema do
    ...
    field :columns, :map       
    timestamps
  end
end
```

**Notice the nested columns map.**

I can insert new Tree row easily like:

```
changeset = Tree.changeset(%Tree{}, %{user_id: user_id, name: x})
      |> Ecto.Changeset.put_embed(:settings, treeSettings)
```

But updating it the same way doesn't work:

```
get_tree = Repo.one! from p in Tree, where: p.name == ^tree["name"], where: p.user_id == ^user_id
settingss = get_tree.settings
settingss = Kernel.update_in(settingss.columns[tree["setting"]][tree["type"]], fn x -> "asdasd" end)
# IO.inspect(settingss) shows correct changes here.
changeset =
    get_tree
    |> Ecto.Changeset.change
    |> Ecto.Changeset.put_embed(:settings, settingss)    
    IO.inspect changeset
```

Gives:

```
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{}, errors: [], data: #Final.Tree<>,
 valid?: true>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can wrap embed into **`Ecto.Changeset.change/2`** before use it in `Ecto.Changeset.html#put_embed/4`

Full example:

**Migration:**

```
defmodule Final.Repo.Migrations.CreateTree do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:trees) do
      add :settings, :map
    end
  end
end
```

**Model Tree:**

```
defmodule Final.Tree do
  use Final.Web, :model

  schema "trees" do
    embeds_one :settings, Final.TreeSettings
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [])
    |> cast_embed(:settings)
  end
end
```

**Model TreeSettings:**

```
defmodule Final.TreeSettings do
  use Final.Web, :model

  embedded_schema do
    field :columns, :map
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:columns])
  end
end
```

**The test:**

```
defmodule Final.TreeTest do
  use Final.ModelCase

  alias Final.Tree

  test "updating nested embed" do
    Repo.insert! Tree.changeset(%Tree{}, %{settings: %{columns: %{"key" => "value", "key2" => "value2"}}})

    tree = Repo.one(Tree)
    settings_changeset = tree.settings
    |> Ecto.Changeset.change(%{columns: %{tree.settings.columns | "key" => "new value"}})

    changeset = tree
    |> Ecto.Changeset.change
    |> Ecto.Changeset.put_embed(:settings, settings_changeset)
    Repo.update! changeset

    assert Repo.one(Tree).settings.columns == %{"key" => "new value", "key2" => "value2"}
  end
end
```

Comment: As I understand it happens because `Nema Ga` has the same key(primary key) in his `settingss` so it should work like updating, but update works only through %Ecto.Changeset{}. So if he will remove the key and use `on_replace: :destroy` then this code will work. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: I believe that the option is `on_replace: :delete`, not `:destroy`. Ecto says: `':on_replace' option for :pages. The only valid options are: ':raise', ':mark_as_invalid', ':delete'`